# Trying to punch sheep again

Tags: json, minecraft

I am unfamiliar with json code outside of making Minecraft models. I am trying to add back the old functionality of punching sheep for wool via a behavior pack for windows 10 edition. This is what I tried adding to the events section.

```
  "minecraft:on_hurt_by_player": {
    "spawn_items": { "table": "loot_tables/entities/sheep_shear.json" },
    "event": "minecraft:on_sheared",
    "target": "self"
    },
```

and

```
  "minecraft:on_hurt_by_player": {
    "spawn_items": { "table": "loot_tables/entities/sheep_shear.json" },
    "on_hurt_by_player"{
        "event": "minecraft:on_sheared",
        "target": "self"
        }
    },
```

I must be missing something. The instruction I have found is so vague and it's not like Microsoft has an open source code to scour either.

Answer (score 1):

`minecraft:on_hurt_by_player` is not a valid trigger condition.

Vanilla does not supply this loot condition, nor anything that would approximate it, so it is unlikely that you will be able to accomplish your change without writing some Java.